# Wocommerce back button from single product back to previous page styling to make it a button

Tags: woocommerce, back-button

I've made a back link to take customer from single product back to product display. I need to know how to give this code a class to make it a button.

The code is

`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'back_button', 10 );`
`function back_button() {`
`global $product;`
`echo ' <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go Back to selection</a> ';`

Thanks

I tried putting

`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'back_button', 10 );`
`function back_button() {`
`global $product;`
`echo ' <button><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go Back to selection</a></button> ';`
`}`

Comment: Class wont make element button. From your code its already button by using <button> tag. If you want class to a button then <button class="my-class"></button>. If you want anchor tag to look like button then remove the button tag and leave only the anchor and add class attribute to it and style it.

Comment: Thank you. I've used the top code because the second code doesn't work. I'm just not sure where to add the class attribute, it just shows as a at the moment. I'm not really a very good coder off the bat :/

Comment: Just do <a href="avascript:history.go(-1)" class="your-calss">Go back to selection</a> . The other code its not working bcs you cant have button and anchor. Buttons can execute js too https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, even though it's not really what I was after but it does the job. I got Wordpress Back button widget plugin. It lets you add “Back” button to your website.

The button can be added via widget, [alg_back_button] shortcode or echo alg_back_button( 'Back' ); function. So until I learn more, this will do. I hope this will help someone else :)